# Order a TreeMap with custom comparator like Excel coordinate order

Tags: java, excel, dictionary, comparator

I'm using a `TreeMap` and its `subMap` to manage Excel files.
I use as key the Excel coordinate.

In Excel the order is like `A`, `B`, `C`, ..., `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, ..., `BA`... but the order I have is `A`, `AA`, `AAA`, `AB`, ..., `B`.

I thought the solution is to use a custom comparator but I don't know how to make it to obtain Excel alphabetical order.

```
Comparator<String> excelOrder= new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        //make order
    }           
};
```

and then use

```
   SortedMap<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>(secondCharComparator);
```

Comment: Compare strings by their length. If equals, compare strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to compare the String by their length (using [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--)) and then lexicographically (this is exactly what's done by default with [`String.compareTo(other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)). The following does exactly that:

```
Comparator<String> excelOrder = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
       int s1Length = s1.length();
       int s2Length = s2.length();
       if (s1Length < s2Length) {
           return -1;
       } else if (s1Length > s2Length) {
           return 1;
       } else {
           return s1.compareTo(s2);
       }
    }           
};
```

Note that if you are using Java 8, this can be written a lot more simply (this code is using the following static import `import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;`):

```
Comparator<String> excelOrder = comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using java 1.8 but  I have an erro The method comparingInt(String::length) is undefined for the type.

Comment: @luca You are missing the static import `import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;`, se my edit